# Microsof Exchange 2013 export to 3rd Party cloud hosting

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, imap, exchange-migration

So I'm trying to export mailboxes off of a local exchange 2013 server and upload them to a hosted VPS running IMAP. So basically migrating mailboxes from exchange to IMAP. I was told that I could move files into the IMAP folder on the server. But I actually dont know if this is an accurate statement or how this would be done.

What is the most effective way to do this transition.

I tried to mass export to a shared folder so first I wanted to assign the required roles, but when running as an administrator I tried the command in powershell to assign import and export roles to the account:

New-ManagementRoleAssigment -Role "Mailbox Import Export" - administrator

This is obviously only the first command of a set, but I was met with an error ManagementRoleAssignment not recognised (something along that line). So I ditched that idea and move to a much more time consuming manual way.

What I have been doing is importing local mailboxes onto a PC connected to the server, exporting them and then importing them again onto a PC with an account connceted to the new IMAP account and syncing the folders, which uploads the emails to the new server.

But like I said, its really taking forever and I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this issue.

I started looking for third party tools and came accross Email Backup wizard. 
It has the option of making the transition from exchange to IMAP. It uploads the backup directly to the IMAP account.

I had to add some impersonation rules to my admin account in order to export the mail accounts. I found an easy Script to run in Exchnage powershell to configure all users:

New-ManagementRoleAssignment -name:impersonnationAssignmentName -Role:ApplicationImpersonation -User:ServerAccount

After this I managed to export the Exchange accounts to my IMAP accounts.

*Just a note, there is a free versio of this application however it only allows you to export upto 25 messages. The paid version is very expensive, but in all honestly, it works!

Comment: Thanks for your sharing :) you could mark the helpful reply as best answer if some other users encounter the same issue, they can quickly find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, you could assign Mailbox Import Export role for administrator in EAC. [image]
And administrator can export a mailbox to .PST files via EAC. In addition, I found an [article](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/43224-export-users-mailboxes-to-pst-files-in-bulk) on how to bulk export mailboxes for your reference.